# Bash command injection

Tags: bash, shell-script

Look at this bash script (`test.sh`):

```
echo "START"
echo $1
echo "END"
```

Here is how I am launching the script:

```
./test.sh `ls`
```

What I want to understand is when `ls` command is executed.

Do you think `ls` is executed *before* `test.sh` call, or do you think `ls` is executed inside the `test.sh` script on line 2.

What I want to do is to be sure the `ls` call is fired inside `test.sh`. How can I do this ?

Comment: Prefer `"$(command)"` over back ticks. However nether should not be used here.

Comment: Warning: command injection is prone to security vulnerabilities. However using this technique inside a program can be useful.

Answer (score 4):

`ls` is run before `test.sh`. It is run as a result of command substitution, which is one of [the word expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) which the shell performs in order to construct the final set of arguments which are provided to the command (`test.sh` in this case); they have to all be finished before the command can run.

If you want to give `test.sh` a command that it should run itself, skip the command substitution. Change `test.sh` to

```
echo "START"
"$1"
echo "END"
```

and call it using `./test.sh ls`.

Comment: It does not work. ls is runned before script...

Comment: How do you see that?

Comment: Instead of calling ls i've called a script which logs

Comment: OK, but how does that tell you that your script isn’t called from `test.sh`?